# Compare data in csv and print changes based on dictionary lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to compare the differences in the csv.

**1st csv:**

```
Device,Priority
Device 1,High
Device 2,Low
Device 3,Medium
Device 4,HIGH
Device 5,Not Found
```

**2nd CSV:**

```
Device,Group 1,Group 2,Group 3,FQDN
Device 2,Operation group MEDIUM,Layer 1 group MEDIUM,Layer 2 group MEDIUM,Some FQDN
Device 3,Operation group LOW,Layer 1 group LOW,Layer 2 group LOW,Some FQDN
Device 1,Operation group HIGH,Layer 1 group HIGH,Layer 2 group HIGH,Some FQDN
Device 4,Alerts,Alerts,Alerts,Some FQDN
Device 5,Operation group LOW,Layer 1 group LOW, Layer 2 group LOW
```

I want my Output csv file to be such that it should print only the changed updated priority from 1st csv and print them to their respective groups.

The relevant groups are:

- Operation(Group 1)
- Layer 1 (Group 2)
- Layer 2(Group 3).

Also, if the group is irrelevant for example, **ALERTS** or some other group then it should skip that iteration and should not print either the device or any info regarding it.

This is how my output file should look like:

```
Device,Group 1,Group 2,Group 3
Device 2,Operation group LOW,Layer 1 group LOW,Layer 2 group LOW
Device 3,Operation group MEDIUM,Layer 1 group MEDIUM,Layer 2 group MEDIUM
```

It skipped Device 4 because it had irrelevant group called `ALERTS`, skipped device 5 because priority wasn't mentioned in 1st csv and it also skipped Device 1 because the priority was same in 1st csv and 2nd csv.

All the groups(rows) will have the same priority in 2nd csv, except for the group names which will be different.(Operation, Layer 1 and Layer 2)

This is what I've tried so far: I have created 2 classes and I have created a dictionary that can lookup the group values if matched:

```
d = {
    ('High', 'Operation group HIGH'): 'Operation group HIGH',
    ('High', 'Layer 1 group HIGH'): 'Layer 1 group HIGH',
    ('High', 'Layer 2 group HIGH'): 'Layer 2 group HIGH'
}
```

and later in my code I have put this, for now I am only testing to get the group 1:

```
for group in groups:
    if device.1stcsvname == group.2ndcsvname:
        try:
            user = d[device.priorities, group.MessageType1]
        except:
            user = 'Not Found'
```

And I'm getting the output:

```
Device,Group 1
Device 1,Operation group HIGH
Device 2,Operation group LOW
Device 3,Operation group MEDIUM
Device 4,Not Found
Device 5,Not Found
```

EDIT 2:
I have created my code and now I am able to print the first group perfectly, but I'm trying to get other 2 groups as well. This is my updated code:

```
d = {
('High', 'High'):
        'Operation group HIGH',

    ('Medium', 'Medium'):
        'Layer 1 group Medium',

    ('Low', 'Low'):
        'Layer 2 group Low',
}
    def get_validgroups(self):
        if 'Operations group' not in self.MessageType1:
            return 'Not Found'
        else:
            return self.MessageType1

    def get_comparison(self):
        if device.priorities.upper() in group.get_validgroups():
            return ''
        else:
            return device.priorities

    def onlychanged(self):
        if group.get_validgroups() == 'Not Found':
            return ''
        else:
            return group.get_comparison()

    def finalchanged(self):
        if device.priorities == 'Not Found':
            return ''
        else:
            return group.onlychanged()
for device in devices: #looping through both csvs
for group in groups:
    if device.1stcsvname== group.2ndcsvname:
        if group.finalchanged() == '': continue
#output with csv writerow here
```

I know this code is too long and this could be well shortened up. Please help guys!

Comment: Just added my code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out my code:

```
import csv

d = {
    ('High', 'High'):
        'Operation group HIGH',

    ('Medium', 'Medium'):
        'Operation group MEDIUM',

    ('Low', 'Low'):
        'Operation group LOW',
}


class DevicePriority:
    def __init__(self, fqdn, priority):
        self.fqdn = fqdn
        self.priority = priority

    @property
    def priorities(self):
        return self.priority

    @property
    def fqdns(self):
        return self.fqdn


def initializefile(file):
    with open('1stcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
        return convertrows(csv.DictReader(f))


def convertrows(rows):
    return [DevicePriority(row['Device'], row['Priority']) for row in rows]

file = r"My\1stcsv.csv"
devices = initializefile(file)


class MHTs:
    def __init__(self, FQDN, MessageType1):
        self.FQDN = FQDN
        self.MessageType1 = MessageType1

    @property
    def devicename(self):
        return self.FQDN

    @property
    def MessageType1(self):
        return self.MessageType1

    def get_validgroups(self):
        if 'Operation' not in self.MessageType1:
            return 'Not Found'
        else:
            return self.MessageType1

    def get_comparison(self):
        if device.priorities.upper() in group.get_validgroups():
            return ''
        else:
            return device.priorities

    def onlychanged(self):
        if group.get_validgroups() == 'Not Found':
            return ''
        else:
            return group.get_comparison()

    def finalchanged(self):
        if device.priorities == 'Not Found':
            return ''
        else:
            return group.onlychanged()

    def finalmhts(self):
        return d[device.priorities, group.onlychanged()]

    def mht2(self):
        if group.get_comparison() == 'High':
            return 'Layer 2 group HIGH
        elif group.get_comparison() == 'Medium':
            return 'Layer 2 group MEDIUM'
        else: 
            group.get_comparison() == 'Low':
            return 'Layer 2 group LOW'

    def mht3(self):
        if group.get_comparison() == 'High':
            return 'Layer 3 group HIGH'
        elif group.get_comparison() == 'Medium':
            return 'Layer 3 group MEDIUM'
        else:
            group.get_comparison() == 'Low'
            return 'Layer 3 group LOW'


def initializefile2(file):
    with open('2ndcsv.csv', 'r', newline='') as i:
        return convertmhts(csv.DictReader(i))


def convertmhts(rows):
    return [MHTs(row['FQDN'], row['MHT_1']) for row in rows]

file = r"My\2ndcsv.csv"
groups = initializefile2(file)


with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvoutput:
    fieldnames = ['Priority', 'FQDN', 'MHT_1', 'MHT_2', 'MHT_3']
    output = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    output.writeheader()

for device in devices:
    for group in groups:
        if device.fqdn == group.devicename:
            if group.finalchanged() == '': continue
            with open('Output.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
                output = csv.writer(csvoutput)
                output.writerows([[device.priority] + [device.fqdn] + [group.finalmhts()] + [group.mht2()] + [group.mht3()]])
```